# Can no longer scroll with keys unless an element is selected

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, shopify

I'm building a Shopify site for a client and I must have done something so that now the keys don't scroll down when the page loads unless I click an element or use tab. I don't have a clue what I did. It might have broken when I made a Vue app to do an API call but I removed that temporarily and that didn't solve anything.

I realize that's not terribly helpful, but maybe someone here has an idea of how I can diagnose this problem? I checked the current theme and the document.hasFocus() is false on that one but the keys work to scroll so I don't think that's the problem. I'm really not sure. I have an added problem that the console log seems to be uncooperative. I get the errors but the console log I write myself don't appear. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

I tried removing the code I suspected was the problem. I checked that the body and HTML css to make sure the overlow-y wasn't hidden. I tried window.focus() and a few other functions I found here and elsewhere but none of that worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing Shopify, I'd suggest using `document.activeElement` to log which element has the focus after the page loads.

```
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

Starting from there, you can see whether it has any event handlers that stop propagation or if it exists outside the `<body>`, which presumably has the keyboard handler(s). Hope this helps.